Dell XPS 13 strange power behavior - won't shut down, BSOD upon attempting to hibernate
I have a Dell XPS 9310 2-in-1 laptop running Windows 10. I generally keep it up to date but have been getting BIOS update fail messages occasionally that I haven't been able to fix. It is otherwise functioning as expected.
The laptop's battery will drain quite quickly (I usually set it to sleep mode and have it go automatically to sleep after 2 mins of inactivity). If I try to shut it down, it restarts immediately with no prompting.
When the battery is low, I will get a "low battery" warning, and within 2 minutes of getting that warning, the screen flashes a "locking" message and goes dark. Immediately after that, the computer restarts itself. Within a few minutes it runs out of power and shuts down.
Sometimes it attempts to hibernate and this works; about 85% of the time, however, I get a generic BSOD saying it failed to shut down correctly. There are no dumps or logs for these BSODs. I do, however, get events from DellPowerManager on the days this occurs. Here's the log:
Error from DellPowerManager.exe:
Message: Error reading registry value by Dell.CommandPowerManager.Common.Alerts+AlertsGroup
Error: (System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationException) at SYS-DS38
You must have administrative credentials to perform this task. Contact your system administrator for assistance.
Inner Error: (System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationException)
Failed to register assembly 'ComponentService, Version=3.14.0.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a298d2ff990ceede'.
Inner Error: (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Dell.CommandPowerManager.Service.ComponentService' is denied.

My account is admin on the laptop.
How do I fix this?

Thanks - I am out of warranty, so I was hoping that wouldn't be the case, but it makes sense.

What have you tried so far regarding resolving the BIOS update issue? Besides BIOS, drivers are also critical to hibernation and other power functions. I would suggest that you still have a good chance of fixing this, but right now you're focused on a symptom, not a root issue. Present your BIOS update problems, what you've tried so far to resolve that, and let's see if we can get you a good solution to THAT that will hopefully move you closer to a successful fix to this secondary issue.
